# What to use as a wall filler?

Tags: walls, plaster, hole, hole-repair

So I posted a few weeks ago here ([Curtain rod ripped off wall](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/279154/curtain-rod-ripped-off-wall/281487#281487)). The issue was that the mortar or whatever was behind the plaster, was crumbling,thus making my curtain pole drop.

Eventually I ended up making 3 holes. I found some kind of metal beam with holes in it. So I was able to screw in piece of wood to it using anchor screws and make the whole thing secure.

[image]

Once covered,the curtain pole will screw into the pieces of wood and will remain sturdy.

What I need is to fill the hole around, primer and paint. What can i use to fill the gaps? Ideally I don't want to replaster for a small section. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're in the states...

You want setting-type joint compound.
[image]

DuraBond specifically should be closer to plaster strength than most other stuff.  You could also use spackle but this will be stronger, take less time to dry, and won't shrink nearly as much.  You can fill the very deep recesses with paper so you don't need quite as much.  Clean out all the loose bits from the hole and mix in a little white glue with the joint compound to make it stick to the old stuff better.  I would apply a few layers at a time and embed mesh drywall tape.

[image]

You don't want the tape to show but it does make the patch stronger.  Smooth the patch with a wider (6 inch?) taping knife and sand flat once it's set.  Wear a good mask (at least n95 but better off p100 respirator), the dust from setting joint compound is not good for you.